# Verbreitung von österreichisch "speiben"

Tags: bavarian, austrian

In Österreich (zumindest im Osten) ist das umgangssprachliche Wort "*speiben*" für "*kotzen*" oder "sich übergeben" gebräuchlich. Wie weit verbreitet ist die Verwendung dieses Wortes? Wird es beispielsweise in Bayern (wo?) noch verwendet?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Das Wort *speiben* (dialektal für *speien*) wird in Österreich (außer Vorarlberg), Bayern und Südtirol umgangssprachlich für *sich übergeben* verwendet. Wikipedia führt das Wort in der [Liste der Austriazismen](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liste_von_Austriazismen).

Für [Österreich gibt es diese Karte](http://vorarlberg.ostarrichi.org/wort-394-reise-at-speiben.html), die anzeigt, wo das Wort verwendet wird:

[image: speiben Verbreitung Österreich]

Die Herkunft: aus dem mittelhochdeutschen spī(w)en, althochdeutsch spī(w)an, verwandt mit dem lateinischen Verb *spuere*. Das alte Wort hat in der Umgangssprache (*sich erbrechen*) und in  in der Hochsprache (*'speien' = 'spucken'*) eine - jeweils andere - Bedeutungseinengung erfahren.

In Österreich gibt es zudem noch folgende umgangssprachliche Varianten:

- sich anspeiben: sich ekeln, enttäuscht sein
- sich ausspeiben: ein volles Geständnis ablegen
- die  Speib'n: das Erbrochene

Das Partizip Perfekt des Verbs ist übrigens *g(e)spieben*.

Answer (score 2):

Zwar etwas anders geschrieben, aber mit gleicher Wortherkunft und Bedeutung ist *"speien"* ein in der deutschen Sprache weit verbreitetes Verb. Es wird im schwäbisch-alemannischen Raum häufig und im hochdeutschen Raum in der gehobenen Sprache in den Bedeutungen *"spucken"* und *"sich erbrechen"* verwendet.

Zur Etymologie (nach Pfeifer) findet sich bei [DWDS](http://www.dwds.de/?qu=speien&view=1):

> **speien** Vb. ‘spucken, sich übergeben’, ahd. *spīwan*, (alem. und südrheinfrk.) *spīan* ‘spucken, aus-, anspeien, sich erbrechen’ (9. Jh.; vgl. *firspīwan* ‘verwerfen, zurückweisen’, 8. Jh.), mhd. *spī(w)en*, (md.) *spūwen*, asächs. *spīwan*, mnd. *spī(g)en*, mnl. *spīen*, *spijen*, *spuwen*, nl. *spuwen*, aengl. *spīwan*, engl. *to spew*, anord. *spȳja*, schwed. *spy*, got. *speiwan* [...]

Das althochdeutsche *'w'* ist weitgehen verloren gegangen, aber im österreichischen *"speiben"* noch als *'b'* enthalten.

Interessant ist auch die gleiche Etymologie und Bedeutung im englischen *"to spew"*.